# Spans in gutenberg

Tags: javascript, block-editor

How can I make a user automatically add spans in the Gutenberg editor? I want to create a "feedback" block - an example from the link: http://bogdans-ultra-awesome-project-10773e.webflow.io

But the problem is that the words are divided into spans and it turns out that the user is locked in a possible number of words. If the spans are 30, then the user can not write 31 word. Animation will disappear and 31 word will be static.

Give recommendations. How to create a block and to wrap (maybe) these spans.

Comment: Usually this kind of wrapping is done in Javascript by the code/plugin used to animate it. I wouldn't warp it on post save because if the animation is ever to be removed your content is still encapsulated in spans.

Comment: @JeffreyvonGrumbkow Could you help me in more detail? I have never been contacted for such a necessity and it is unclear to me how to wrap it in javascript. Or maybe there is a textbook? Thank you very much.

Comment: Then don't bother writing it yourself. Take a look at http://velocityjs.org/blast/